# PHPで、MYSQLへのUPDATEでエラー

Tags: php

PHPで、MYSQLへUPDATEするソースを書いていますが、エラーになります。
エラー内容は下記です。

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 argument, 7 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\user_update_commit.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\user_update_commit.php(30): PDOStatement->execute('\xE5\xB1\xB1\xE7\x94\xB0', '\xE5\x8F\x8B\xE9\x87\x8C', '\xE3\x83\xA4\xE3\x83\x9E\xE3\x83\x80', '\xE3\x83\xA6\xE3\x83\xAA', 'yuri', 'yuririn1969', '1') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Portfolio\user_update_commit.php on line 30
```

エラーを見ると、引数が不足しているようですが、下記のようにvar_dumpしたところ、想定通りの値が出力されます。

```
var_dump($_REQUEST['sei']);
var_dump($_REQUEST['mei']);
var_dump($_REQUEST['sei_kana']);
var_dump($_REQUEST['mei_kana']);
var_dump($_REQUEST['user']);
var_dump($_REQUEST['password']);
var_dump($_REQUEST['seq']);
```

何が原因か不明なため、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。

```
    <?php

    try{
        require_once('db_connect.php');
        $sql=$pdo->prepare('update user_table set last_name=?, first_name=?, last_name_kana=?, first_name_kana=?, user=?, password=? where id=? ');
            if(empty($_REQUEST['sei']) || empty($_REQUEST['mei']) || empty($_REQUEST['sei_kana']) || empty($_REQUEST['mei_kana']) || empty($_REQUEST['user']) || empty($_REQUEST['password']))
                {
                    echo '未入力の項目があります。';
                }
                else if(!preg_match('/\A[ァ-ヴー]+\z/u', $_REQUEST['sei_kana']) || !preg_match('/\A[ァ-ヴー]+\z/u', $_REQUEST['mei_kana']))
                    {
                         echo 'カナ名は全角カナで入力してください。';
                    }
                    else if(!preg_match('/\A[a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-`{-~]+\z/u', $_REQUEST['user']))
                        {
                            echo 'ユーザーは半角英数字記号で入力します';
                        }
                        else if(!preg_match('/\A[a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-`{-~]{10,}\z/u', $_REQUEST['password']))
                            {
                                echo 'パスワードは半角英数字記号10文字以上で入力します。';
                            }
                            else if(!preg_match('/\A[a-zA-Z0-9!-\/:-@[-`{-~]{10,}\z/u', $_REQUEST['password2']))
                                {
                                    echo 'パスワードは半角英数字記号10文字以上で入力します。';
                                }
                                else if($_REQUEST['password'] !== $_REQUEST['password2'])
                                    {
                                        echo '2つのパスワードが一致してません。';
                                    }
                                    else if($sql->execute(
                                            htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['sei'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
                                            htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mei'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
                                            htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['sei_kana'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
                                            htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mei_kana'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
                                            htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['user'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
                                            htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
                                            htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['seq'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8')))
                                        {
                                            echo '更新に成功しました。';
                                        }
                                            else {
                                                    echo '更新に失敗しました。';
                                                }}
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo "次がエラーの内容です。;" .$e->getMessage();
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 引数が不足しているようですが、

`PDOStatement::execute() expects at most 1 argument, 7 given` = 「1引数を期待しているのに7個も渡された」（意訳）とある通り、引数が不足しているのではなく過剰に渡しています。

実際に、PHPの関数マニュアルにある[PDOStatement::executeのページ](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdostatement.execute.php)を確認してみましょう。
このメソッドが求めているのは、プリペアドステートメントに対して「バインドパラメータと同数の要素からなる値の配列」となっています。
それに対して、実際のコードではパラメータの分だけそれぞれ別の引数として渡しています。

そのため、配列1個のみの要求に対してパラメータ数の7個分の引数を指定しまっているため、実際のエラー原因となっています。

### 対応例

このコードの状態を前提としてピンポイントな対処を考えると、単純に渡したい値をまるごと一つの配列としてあげればエラー自体は解消されると思います。

（元コードから整形して抜粋）

```php
$sql->execute(
  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['sei'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mei'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['sei_kana'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mei_kana'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['user'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
  htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['seq'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8')
)
```

↓
「7個の引数」を配列としてひとまとめにして「1個の引数」に変える。
↓

```php
$sql->execute(
  [
    htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['sei'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mei'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['sei_kana'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['mei_kana'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['user'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8'),
    htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['seq'],ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5,'UTF-8')
  ]
)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。解決しました。